# Find_in_set returns an empty set?

Tags: mysql, find-in-set

I have some questions about the set type in `find_in_set`
here is the code:

```
create table set_test(id int,set_col SET('a','b','c','d'));
insert into set_test(id,set_col) values(1,'a,b'),(2,'a,b,b');
select * from set_test where find_in_set('a,b',set_col)
```

return empty set!!!
why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation of function [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

> **FIND_IN_SET(str, strlist)**
>
> Returns a value in the range of `1` to `N` if the string `str` is in the string list `strlist` consisting of `N` substrings. A string list is a string composed of substrings separated by `“,”` characters.

Its second argument is a string containing values separated by comma. The value you passed to `FIND_IN_SET()` (the column `set_col` having the type `SET`) matches this description. However, its first argument should be only one of the values contained in the list. `a,b` is not a valid value to pass as first argument to `FIND_IN_SET()` as it contains to values: `a` and `b`. You should pass it either `'a'` or `'b'` if you want it to find something.

This is also documented at the end of the paragraph which says:

> This function does not work properly if the first argument contains a comma (`“,”`) character.

Answer (score 1):

you can not use `find_in_set` function to search for a string with a comma in it `'a,b'`, but only for any string which separated by comma like `a` or `b` or `c`, so if you try this will work correctly:

```
select * from set_test where find_in_set('a',set_col);
```

but in your case you may use `like`:

```
select * from set_test where set_col like '%a,b%';
```

Comment: Solving my similar problem: EXACT: "select * from set_test where find_in_set('a',set_col) AND find_in_set('b',set_col)";  ANY: "select * from set_test where find_in_set('a',set_col) OR find_in_set('b',set_col)";

Answer (score 0):

The [find_in_set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function returns a numeric value of the search result, or 0 if not found.

You should change:
select * from set_test where find_in_set('a,b',set_col);

To:
select * from set_test where find_in_set('a,b',set_col) > 0;